# Jetpack Compose - too much margin

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to build BusinessCardApp from Google's "Build a Basic Layout"  part of Android Basics with Compose. However while my code seems to have no mistakes, the UI seems like this(too much margin).(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU7OQ.jpg)What to do? While it should be like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAPyl.jpg)

I tried modifier.weight as 3/2 for each part in "Birlestir" function. It doesn't work.
I nearly did everything the same with this example, but it does not work. https://proandroiddev.com/jetpack-compose-basics-part-2-79eb045a4397

I think the solution must be in the first two functions, either in "Birlestir", or in "BizCardApp".

```
`package com.example.businesscardapp

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.border
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.ImageVector
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.vectorResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.example.businesscardapp.ui.theme.BusinessCardAppTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            BusinessCardAppTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Birlestir()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun Birlestir() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        BizCardApp(modifier = Modifier.weight(3F))
        BizCardAppBottom(modifier = Modifier.weight(2F))

    }
}


@Composable
fun BizCardApp(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val image = painterResource(R.drawable.istockphoto_1413766112_612x612)
    Column(
       modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
       // verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        // .weight(1f)
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom
    ) {
        val imageModifier = Modifier
            .width(150.dp)
            .height(150.dp)
            .border(BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Black))
        Image(
            painter = image,
            contentDescription = "cv picture",
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight,
            modifier = imageModifier
        )
        Text(
            text = "Mahmut Yuruk",
            //text = "Hi From Mahmut", olarak da yazılabilir,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            modifier = modifier
           .padding(0.dp, 8.dp, 0.dp, 8.dp),
            //textAlign = TextAlign.Center, istenirse eklenebilir
            //color = Color(0xFF3ddc84) istenirse eklenebilir
        )
        Text(
text = "Junior Android Programmer",
            //text = "Hi From Mahmut", olarak da yazılabilir,
            fontSize = 12.sp,
           //textAlign = TextAlign.Center, istenirse eklenebilir
            modifier = modifier,
            //color = Color(0xFF3ddc84) istenirse eklenebilir
        )
    }
}
@Composable
fun BizCardAppBottom(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
Column(
    modifier = modifier
        //.background(color = Color(0xFFEADDFF))
        .padding(0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp, 50.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    //                        .weight(1f)   "+2 522 477 85 65", social = "@datmusclewow", email = "mernovski@gmail.com"
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
){
    BizCardAppBottom1()
    BizCardAppBottom2()
    BizCardAppBottom3()
}
}
@Composable
fun BizCardAppBottom1(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier
            //.background(color = Color(0xFFEADDFF))
            .padding(8.dp),
        //verticalAlignment = Alignment.Vertical,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ){
        Icon(
            modifier = Modifier.size(34.dp),
            imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_contact_phone_24),
            contentDescription = "Some icon",
            tint = Color.Unspecified
        )
        Spacer(Modifier.width(20.dp))

        Text(
            text = "+2 522 477 85 65",
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            modifier = modifier,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            color = Color(0xFF3ddc84)
        )
}
}
@Composable
fun BizCardAppBottom2(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier
            //.background(color = Color(0xFFEADDFF))
            .padding(8.dp),
//verticalAlignment = Alignment.Vertical,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Icon(
            modifier = Modifier.size(34.dp),
            imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_people_outline_24),
            contentDescription = "Some icon",
            tint = Color.Unspecified
        )
        Spacer(Modifier.width(20.dp))

        Text(
            text = "@datmusclewow",
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            modifier = modifier,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            color = Color(0xFF3ddc84)
        )
    }
}
@Composable
fun BizCardAppBottom3(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier
            //.background(color = Color(0xFFEADDFF))
            .padding(0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp, 50.dp),
        //verticalAlignment = Alignment.Vertical,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Icon(
            modifier = Modifier.size(34.dp),
            imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_mail_24),
            contentDescription = "Some icon",
            tint = Color.Unspecified
        )
        Spacer(Modifier.width(20.dp))

        Text(
            text = "mernovski@gmail.com",
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            modifier = modifier,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            color = Color(0xFF3ddc84)
        )
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    BusinessCardAppTheme {
        Birlestir()
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You were supported to use `Align` And `Arrangment` Of Column so that you can get your desired look.

I have made your example. You Can See it here.

**Example Preview**

[image: preview]

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.border
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.ColumnScope
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBar
import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarDefaults
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.ImageVector
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.vectorResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.example.jetpackcomposeplayground.R
import com.example.jetpackcomposeplayground.ui.theme.JetpackComposePlayGroundTheme

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun BizCard() {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text(text = "Sample App") }, colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = Color.Blue
                )
            )
        }
    ) {

        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(it)) {
            TopCard()
            BottomCard()
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun ColumnScope.TopCard() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(3f)
            .padding(8.dp)
            .border(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Blue),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.istockphoto_1413766112_612x612),
            contentDescription = "",
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(90.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight
        )

        Text(
            "Full Name",
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontSize = 22.sp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(5.dp),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )

        Text(
            "Title Role",
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(5.dp),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )

    }
}


@Composable
fun ColumnScope.BottomCard() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(2f)
            .padding(8.dp)
            .border(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Blue),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom
    ) {
        BottomItem()
        BottomItem()
        BottomItem()
        BottomItem()
    }
}

@Composable
fun BottomItem() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(5.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.istockphoto_1413766112_612x612),
            contentDescription = "",
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(22.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
        Text(
            "+4 00 00 00 00",
            fontSize = 15.sp,
        )
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    JetpackComposePlayGroundTheme {
        BizCard()
    }
}
```

Hope this works!! Happy Compose.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Chirag! Can you emphasize the missing/faulty parts in my code? Because I still cannot understand. My code have Align and Arrangement. Did I used them wrong? Or something missing?

Comment: Did you tried the code?

Comment: Thank you a lot for your efforts, it works. But I want to understand why my code doesn't work? Everything is correct (so it seems).

Comment: Okay, I'll give you explanation shortly